# Feed an object generated by an asynchronous function into a function (i.e. for D3)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js

I have an asynchronous piece of code that returns an object. In this case, the createprimatives callback.

```
var url = "http://example.com/example.ttl";
createprimatives(url, function(dummy) {
  console.log(dummy);
});
```

I'd like to feed that object to another function.

I tried implementing the top suggestion in:
 [How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)  by rewriting the code with a callback calling another:

```
var url = "http://example.com/example.ttl";
loader(url, function(graph) {
  var height = 800;
  var width = 800;
  console.log(graph);
  draw(width,height,graph);
});

function loader(url, fn) {
  createprimatives(url, function(dummy) {
    console.log(dummy);
    fn(dummy);
  });
};
```

Either console.log(dummy) or console.log(graph) will return the same object as the simple code in the first snippet in an asynchronous manner.

However, draw fails with a message similar to 'TypeError: "x" is not a function' [1] .
draw calls code for a Force-directed D3 graph, so it is more like :
"TypeError: svgContainer.append(...).attr(...).selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function" .

i.e.:

The object generated by a console.log when fed into

```
draw(height,width,graph);
```

works just fine if the object is assigned to the variable graph first (i.e hardcoding the result of the first code snippet in the loader function) .

```
var graph = pasted console.log(graph) output into code
```

However I get a TypeError if I wait for the XMLHTTPRequest embedded in createprimatives and do not initially assign to graph. I think I need a piece of code that waits for the XMLHTTPRequest and create primatives, and then calls draw while passing the object generated from the code in the createprimatives function.

[1]
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function

Comment: You might be making this more complicated than it is. `createprimatives` calls your callback with some object. You pass that object to `draw`. `draw` complains that the object doesn't have the right shape. So what is `graph` and how is it wrong? We probably need to see the source of `createprimatives` and `draw` to tell you what the problem is, but it sounds like you're most of the way there yourself.

Comment: Yes Rob, the problem is in createprimatives. My code gave D3 a string, when it should be an object. Line 62: https://github.com/bshambaugh/node-arc-d3/blob/master/js/createprimatives.js 

Resolved.